# Is it possible to calculate distances between European postcodes in Excel as a lookup?

Tags: excel, distance, lookup, postal-code

I have over 24,000 lines of data in Excel and am looking to calculate distances between European addresses.  Currently doing this address by address and wanted to know if extracting this data was possible....which has led me to this forum.  Only having college level programming skills (in pascal a long time ago) I am keen on knowing if this is possible via a lookup style request to a separate data source.

Comment: welcome!  Please see "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve] to update your question showing what you've tried and where you're stuck.  Also, reading the [tour] will earn you your first badge.

Comment: It is almost certainly possible. "Is it possible" almost always has a "yes" answer in programming. The more relevant question is "how" -- but your question is a bit too vague to say how.

Comment: You'd either need to use a webservice to convert addresses to longitude/latitude coordinates, then use some simple maths to convert to distance: But this would give you "as the crow flies" distances. Or you could use this amazing Google Sheets solution by Amit Agarwal, which provides direct lookup functionality with the result based on walking or driving distance, e.g. `=GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE(A1, B1, "driving")` https://www.labnol.org/google-maps-sheets-200817